# How to Validate Auth Token from Request Header

Tags: spring, middleware, sap-commerce-cloud

I have 2 servers. 1st is SAP Hybris. 2nd is Middleware server.

Middleware Server will receive API call from Hybris and then it will execute and process the request.

Now I want to make this API Call secure with OAuth 2.0 such that any server having valid token can only call middleware server through API.

I have created user in "OAuth Client" in Hybris.When any request come with access token,I need to validate whether the token is valid or not.

Can anyone guide me in configuring this OAuth mechanisam in Middleware (Spring Boot)?

Note: The OAuth token is generated by Hybris.

Comment: Creating "OAuth Client" in Hybris is useless, as the API is on the middleware. Hybris is simply hitting the middleware.

Comment: Hi @FarrukhChishti : i have created seprate server for OAuth Token. I have followed below Example:
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot-oauth2-client-grant

This example works perfectly fine. but when i integrate this OAuth server with my Middlware then i got error "Invalid Token"

It seems that there is version issue in OAuth server and my Middleware.

Comment: In OAuth Server Version is :

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

In My Middlware:

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Answer (score 0):

You need to create client tokens from middleware, not hybris. If you will call hybris API, your middleware need hybris OAuth client tokens.